# File Import in an extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x, file-import

I use to import files from another application via JSON into TYPO3. The imported files are saved in a specific storage. The associated records are created in sys_file. So far everything looks good.
Now I'd like to add the imported files to a certain table. For that I use the approach of the news extension V8.5.2 according NewsImportService.php. There is a function hydrateNewsRecord() which makes media (file) relation. Therefor I use following code:

```
$media = $objectManager->get(\Zhaw\ZhawContinuingEducation\Domain\Model\FileReference::class);
$media->setFileUid($file->getUid());
\\ add new file to field
$newCourse->addContactImage1($media);
...
\\ add to table course
$courseRepo->add($newCourse);
...
$persistenceManager->persistAll();
```

During test I always get the error (due to persistence manager): **Table 'typo3_www.tx_zhawcontinuingeducation_domain_model_filereference' doesn't exist**

I also included under domain/model FileReference.php and added in setup.typoscript:

```
objects {
        TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference.className = Zhaw\ZhawContinuingEducation\Domain\Model\FileReference
}
persistence {
    storagePid =
    classes {
        Zhaw\ZhawContinuingEducation\Domain\Model\FileReference {
            mapping {
                tableName = sys_file_reference
                columns {
                    uid_local.mapOnProperty = originalFileIdentifier
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The table tx_zhawcontinuingeducation_domain_model_filereference is not necessary, because it already exists in the core. Does anybody know, what I'm missing?

Comment: Which TYPO3 version are you using?

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to mention. We are using TYPO3 V10.4.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping model classes like that in TypoScript isn't possible anymore since TYPO3 10.0. You'll need to add a `EXT:extension/Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/Classes.php` file to your extension with the following content:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

return [
    \Zhaw\ZhawContinuingEducation\Domain\Model\FileReference::class => [
        'tableName' => 'sys_file_reference',
        'properties' => [
            'originalFileIdentifier' => [
                'fieldName' => 'uid_local'
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

More about this you can find here: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.0/Breaking-87623-ReplaceConfigpersistenceclassesTyposcriptConfiguration.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my day. That heldep me to solve my problem. After I changed my "old" code it works like a charm.